# How to handle this ErrorException in PHP

Tags: php, exception, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to format user input with the following code:

```
$userInput="blalalbla";//assume the user is inputing wrong data, they are supposed to input it like "12:30"
try{

  $timeStr=explode(":",$userInput);
  $time=(new Datetime())->setTime($timeStr[0],$timeStr[1]);
}catch(ErrorException $e){

}
```

However, if the input is not in the right format, laravel4 will always fire an ErrorException and I have no way of catching it. Since the user input can be wrong in different ways, I thought this was the most elegant way of handling validation. As ridiculous as it sounds like, ErrorExceptions seem to be un-catchable. What other options do I have?

Comment: `catch(ErrorException $e)`

Comment: Doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Are you certain that this particular block of code is the one throwing the exception?

Comment: That block isn't throwing the error. DateTime isn't Laravel

Comment: From code above, the ErrorException is "Undefined offset: 1"

Comment: Always validate user input before trying to parse it. Always.

Comment: Well, I was trying to use Exception to handle validation... So with PHP I need to go through every scenario and check them one by one? :((((

Comment: You can validate the user input by using a regular expression for example.

Comment: You can use Exceptions to help your validation, but you have to define what you expect before doing anything with it. Do not rely on pure PHP errors, since engine itself is not aware of business logic in your application, and it does not know what format to expect.

Comment: Thanks, I don't remember facing the same situation when using python... And I'd better go learn regx right now X(

Answer (score 1):

The actual error received in your code is a PHP Notice. You can't `catch` it because it isn't an exception at that point in time. Laravel defines the class `Illuminate\Exception\Handler` and uses PHP's `set_error_handler()` to turn PHP errors into ErrorExceptions.

To use a try/catch block in your controller, you'll have to throw the exception yourself in that area (or use code that throws exceptions). However, as most have commented, you should be doing appropriate input checking and sanitation prior to actually using the input in any code. Whether or not poor input throws exceptions is totally up to you.

Answer (score 0):

set a global error handler

```
set_exception_handler (handler);

function handler($e) {
    if($e instanceof TheExceptionYouWantToHandle) {
        //then handle it
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to handle all the errors, just the ones that's possibly going to happen in this part of the code